# Products Shortcode is Displaying Single Product Page Price for all Products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode

I've added a Products Shortcode to the single product page in an accordion section.  The Products are displaying as expected with the relevant names, but the price shown for each is the Single Product Price.

Does anyone have any ideas about what's happening here?

I have written the following code in my functions file to retrieve the cross sell ids that I pass into the shortcode.  Could this be causing conflict?

```
global $product;


    //Check for Cross Sells
    if ( !empty( $product->get_cross_sell_ids() ) ) { 

        $cross_sell_ids = implode(',',$product->get_cross_sell_ids());    t

    }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: edit your question to show the shortcode you use.